# Form within a form in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I created an application form with HTML and on that application the user has to upload his resume. I was thinking to create a form within the form to let the user upload his resume such as:

```
<div class="application-form">
    <form class="contact-form" action="application-form.php" method="post">
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first">
        </div>
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last">
        </div>
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="resume">
            <form action="">
                <label>Resume</label>
                <input type="file" name="resume">
                <button type="submit">Submit Resume</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Seems this is not possible in HTML. What is the best alternative? thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the need for the nested form here...just remove it and make the file upload part of the application-form.php handler.  Also add the enctype attribute to your `<form>` to accept files.

```
<div class="application-form">
    <form class="contact-form" action="application-form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first">
        </div>
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last">
        </div>
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="application-data">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="resume">
            <label>Resume</label>
            <input type="file" name="resume">
            <button type="submit">Submit Resume</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```